# Check if index exists in WebSQL

Tags: javascript, web-sql

Is there a way to check if an index exists for a table in WebSQL database? 
I'm using `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INDEX_GUID ON TABLE PERSONS` for creation. But if index already exists I get an error:

```
{
    code: 5, // SYNTAX_ERR - from docs
    message: "could not prepare statement (1 index INDEX_GUID already exists)"
}
```

The best solution for me would be to list all indexes of a table.

Comment: Using `IF NOT EXISTS` doesn't help in my case. I need to know if index exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this but it's a workaround. I hope that error messages are allways in english.

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql(
        "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INDEX_GUID ON TABLE PERSONS",
        [],
        function (tx, rs) {
            // index created
        },
        function (tx, e) {
            if (e.message.indexOf("already exists") == -1) {
                // index not created - already exists
            }
        });
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if (e.message.indexOf("already exists") == -1) {

should be a !=

i.e.

```
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(
            "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INDEX_GUID ON TABLE PERSONS",
            [],
            function (tx, rs) {
                // index created
            },
            function (tx, e) {
                if (e.message.indexOf("already exists") != -1) {
                    // index not created - already exists
                }
            });
        );
     });
```